# header file doesn't seem to be recognizing variables from main function

Tags: c++, header, computer-science, cin

First of all, I am aware it is not good practice to do anything other then declare your functions etc... in the header file, but my teacher wanted us to follow this format so I am.

The goal of this particular function is to store user input into the various arrays in 'int main'.

The issue im getting with this function, as well as some others is that the compiler is throwing various errors I think are related to it not being able to recognize the arrays from 'int main'. (Just my guess).

Disclaimer: I have been working on this program since 4 pm till the time of posting this at 2 am so if im doing something really stupid I apologize, im honestly just going through the motions at this point.

```
//header file

void getVisitorInfo(int* age[], double* hours[], string* country[]) {
  cout<<"Enter your country: ";
  getline(cin, country[vCount]);
  cout<<endl;

  cout<<"Enter your age: ";
  cin>>age[vCount];
  cout<<endl;

  cout<<"Enter the number of hours you explored: ";
  cin>>hours[vCount];
  cout<<endl;

  vCount++;
}
```

```
//main file
const int max = 100;

int main() {
  int age[max], vOldest, vYoungest, vAverage, userChoice;
  double hours[max], vShortest, vLongest, vAverage;
  string country[max];
  bool pass;

//etc...
}
```

```
//a few of many errors
test.cpp: In function ‘void getVisitorInfo(int**, double**, std::string**)’:
test.cpp:84:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::istream&, std::string*&)’
   getline(cin, country[vCount]);
                               ^
test.cpp:84:31: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/string:53:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.tcc:1068:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::getline(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, _CharT)
     getline(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.tcc:1068:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:84:31: note:   mismatched types ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}’
   getline(cin, country[vCount]);
                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:2793:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::getline(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     getline(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:2793:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:84:31: note:   mismatched types ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}’
   getline(cin, country[vCount]);
                               ^
test.cpp:89:6: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ and ‘int*’)
   cin>>age[vCount];
      ^
```

Comment: In the parameter list, `int* age[]` is wrong. It should be `int age[]`. Rinse, and repeat for the other broken args. They're all declared as pointers to pointers; they should just be pointers in one fashion (`int *arg`) or another (`int arg[]`).

Comment: Regarding `getVisitorInfo()`: `int *age[]` is an array of `int*` which decays to `int**` because arrays in function parameters decay to pointers in general. Are you sure that you didn't intend `int age[]` or `int *age` (what's actually the same)?

Comment: I don't see `std` scope, are you `using namespace std;`?

Comment: @Scheff That error is complaining because of the issue you mentioned in previous comments. OP is trying to pass a `std::string*` to `std::getline`, which only accepts `std::string` (as the error message also mentions).